# Нужно отобразить кнопки найдя строку "admin" и пароль "1234" в БД

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void goodsFrame_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=1234";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand auth = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sporthit.сотрудники WHERE логин_сотрудника = '" + Convert.ToString("admin") + "' AND пароль = '" + Convert.ToString("1234") + "'",conDataBase);
            conDataBase.Open();
            MySqlDataReader rd = auth.ExecuteReader();
            //rd.Read();
            try
            {
                //auth.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //
                if (rd.Read())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Login: {0}, Password: {1}", rd.GetString("логин_сотрудника")), rd.GetString("пароль"));
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Неправильный логин или пароль!", "Ошибка авторизации");
                }
                rd.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
            }


            add.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.addButton;
            remove.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.removeButton;


        }
```

Необходимо выбрать из базы данных строку с именем admin и паролем 1234, в программировании не особо понимаю, рассчитываю на Вашу помощь, заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: А в чем помощь нужна, вы так и не написали...Мы видим код, который как то должен отработать, но что конкретно не получается у вас?

Comment: MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Login: {0}, Password: {1}", rd.GetString("логин_сотрудника")), rd.GetString("пароль"));


В этой строке,когда запускаю программу пишет, что с индексацией проблема, не знаю, как это решить

Comment: Или просто подскажите, как можно написать код, чтобы бралась строка с вышесказанными наименованиями и проходила проверка...Если пользователь авторизировался, как админ, то у него есть определённые кнопки, а если, как другой пользователь, то эти кнопки, соответственно, скрываются